# Proper way to run gradle app with alpn-boot?

Tags: gradle, http2

I'm trying to run my jar with a bootclass path in gradle but it doesn't look like it's particularly working.

The dependency I need is alpn-boot which is needed for http2 support.

My gradle configuration look like this:

`dependencies{
    compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:3.2.1'
    runtime 'org.mortbay.jetty.alpn:alpn-boot:8.1.7.v20160121'
}`

And I'm tring to run it with the args

`run {
    args["-Xbootclasspath/p:build/install/myapp/lib/alpn-boot-alpn-boot:8.1.7.v20160121.jar"]
}`

Instead I get:

`[main] INFO com.relayrides.pushy.apns.ApnsClient - OpenSSL (via netty-tcnative) not available; will use JDK SSL provider.`

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Are you sure that the relative path `build/install/...` is properly resolved when you run the application ?

Comment: Yes that's the correct place of the file.

Comment: Your question shows part of the logs only. They show that your application does not use OpenSSL, but JDK's SSL provider. So far, so good. It is not clear what is it that does not work for you. You have to make sure that Vertx can make use of Jetty's ALPN implementation. If it can, then your setup should work just fine.